# Objective -c properties - Can't change a subview's color with a declared property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a view with a subview whose alpha and backgroundcolor I would like to change through the use of declared properties. I have written some code as below and it works fine to change the alpha, but the background color is not changed when the property is set to a new value. Any help would be appreciated please.

```
    @interface MyView : UIView {
     float viewAlpha;
     UIColor *viewColor;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) float viewAlpha;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) UIColor *viewColor;



    @implementation MyView

    @synthesize viewAlpha, viewColor;

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
        if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

        self.viewAlpha = 1.0; 
        self.viewColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIView *infoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
        infoView.alpha = self.viewAlpha;
           infoView.backgroundColor = self.viewColor;
        [self addSubview:infoView];
        [infoView release];
        }


return self;
}
```

Comment: I can't quite tell which part of your program isn't working?

Comment: Hi Ed,

If I declare an instance of the view above in another view, I can change the alpha by setting the declared property as shown below, which works fine. However, if I try to set the backgroundcolor, it has no effect.

Code:
MyView *myView = ....
[self addSubview:myView];

myView.viewAlpha= 0.5; <<This works
myView.viewColor = [UIColor redColor]; << This has no effect

Comment: Why do you need separate alpha and UIColor members? an instance of UIColor contains alpha information.

Comment: How do you instantiate MyView?

Comment: Nall - Yes, I agree. I just included the alpha to illustrate that setting alpha through a property works but not the background color.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to write a custom setter and flag that your view needs to redraw when it changes.  It'd be a good idea to do this for both the alpha and the color.

Comment: Hi Benno. Writing a custom setter with a redraw request is something I had in mind, but it seems odd that one can change the background color form within a view without calling redraw but cannot set it from outside.

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect both to fail.  I'm unsure as to why one works, but I suspect it's because one's a static value and the other is an object reference.